# Создание ассоциативного массива в Java

Tags: php, java, массивы

Имеется массив в PHP:

```
$array = [
    "status" => FALSE, 
    "len" => 3, "msg" => "this String Hello", "data" => [0 => ["name" => "Vasya", "phone" => "123"], 1 => ["name" => "Anna", "phone" => "222"], 2 => ["name" => "John", "phone" => "300"]]
];
```

требуется создать такой же массив в Java, как мне это сделать ?

Comment: Создать самый обычный класс, три объекта и запихать их в массив.

Comment: Можно поподробнее, желательно с примером кода...

Answer (score 4):

Ну лично я бы сделал это примерно вот так:

```
public class Client {

    private String name;
    private String phone;

    public Client(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    // Getters ans setters

}

public class DataClients {

    private boolean status;
    private String message;
    private List<Client> clients;

    public DataClients(boolean status, String message, List<Client> clients) {
         this.status = status;
         this.message = message;
         this.clients = clients;
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

И потом можно было бы где-нибудь сделать примерно вот так:

```
List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
clients.add(new Client("Vasya", "123"));
clients.add(new Client("Anna", "222"));
clients.add(new Client("John", "300"));
DataClients dataClients = new DataClients(true, "message", clients);
```

Данный подход будет более понятным для других программистов, нежели использовать непонятный никому сбор данных в массиве. Также можно было бы еще прикрутить паттерн "Builder" для DataClients, но это уже по желанию...

Comment: Супер, это отличное решение моей задачи, спасибо!

Comment: Отметьте вопрос правильным, если он вам помог...

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, простого способа создать такую структуру данных нет.
Есть пара обходных маневров, которые можно попробовать

1. Создать мапу таким образом:

   ```
   Map<String, Object> associativeMap = new HashMap<>();
   ```

   после этого ее можно наполнять парами как-то так:

   ```
   associativeMap.put("len", 3);
   associativeMap.put("msg", "This string hello");
   associativeMap.put("data", new Object[]{"name", 3, new String[]{"Hi", "Bye"}});
   ```

   Но в этом случае будет утрачена проверка типов и, таким образом, типобезопасность на этапе компиляции.
2. Можно пойти путем создания гетерогенного списка (heterogenous list, HList), как описано [здесь](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/heterogeneous-lists-and-the-limits-of-the-java-type-system/). Но это путь для смелых (см. код по ссылке)

Comment: так извращаться, как правило, незачем. но TC хочет мапу с произвольными типами, кто его знает, зачем она ему?)

Comment: Если код для пункта 2 важен для ответа, то нужно его добавить в сам ответ. Если ссылка на сторонний сайт устареет, доступ к коду исчезнет.

Comment: такой код, в обычных условиях, лучше не писать). а если что, его можно легко нагуглить по HList Java, так что не стоит его сюда постить - пугать народ))